# Placing divider at a certain position in ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listactivity, divider

I'm using a `ListActivity` with an `ArrayAdapter`. I have an array of `String`s, and I want to put a divider after the 5th `String` in the list. Is there any way to do this? Sorry if there are duplicates, just did not find what I was looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your adapter class and custom listitem xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hack.

Add a divider view at last in your list_item's layout file and give it an Id. Now in your custom adapter class,you can set that view's visibility depending on the position whether you want it to be shown or not,in getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

A property of Listview will help you:

```
android:divider =  (color or drawable)
```

And also

```
android:dividerHeight = (integer in dp)
```